# WPF - How to not do DragDrop on MouseDoubleClick?

Tags: wpf, drag-and-drop, mouseevent

I've got a control with rectangles in a grid. I can drag rectangles from one cell to another within the grid. But I also need to double-click on a rectangle to bring up an edit dialog. The issue here is that just pressing the left mouse button on the rectangle will initiate a `MouseMove` event and cause the `DragDrop` to initiate when it's not wanted.

Here's the `MouseMove` and `MouseDoubleClick` event handlers:

```
Dim IsDragging As Boolean = False
Private Sub SchedItem_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseMove
    If IsDragging Then Exit Sub
    If e.LeftButton = MouseButtonState.Pressed Then
        Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(Sub()
                                   IsDragging = True
                                   DragDrop.DoDragDrop(Me, Me, DragDropEffects.Move)
                                   IsDragging = False
                               End Sub)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub SchedItem_PreviewMouseDoubleClick(sender As Object, e As MouseButtonEventArgs) Handles Me.PreviewMouseDoubleClick
    itmEditTask_Click(Nothing, Nothing)
    e.Handled = True
End Sub
```

I tried not initiating the `MouseMove` by attempting to determine the distance the mouse had traveled since the `MouseLeftButtonDown` event.  But the x & y numbers are all over the place and I can't reliably set a threshold value. Here's that code:

```
Private mPos As Point
Private Sub SchedItem_MouseLeftButtonDown(sender As Object, e As MouseButtonEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseLeftButtonDown
    mPos = Mouse.GetPosition(Nothing)
End Sub

Private Function IsReallyMouseMove() As Boolean
    Dim pPos As Point = Mouse.GetPosition(Nothing)
    Debug.WriteLine(Math.Abs(mPos.X - pPos.X) & ", " & Math.Abs(mPos.Y - pPos.Y))
    IsReallyMouseMove = Math.Abs(mPos.X - pPos.X) > 10 OrElse Math.Abs(mPos.Y - pPos.Y) > 10
End Function
```

So I'm hoping someone has done this and can provide some direction.

Answer (score 0):

best way - redesign.
Make you item draggable by some object in item element. (Maybe little dot with different drag cursor)
Other area will handle double click.